# MySQL Table in use

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded MySQL directory `/var/lib/mysql` to my computer to test out.

This is what I see near the table wp_posts:

[image: Table in use message]

I have tried to select the table above and repair it but it didn't work.

These are the table files:

[image: files in terminal ls -l]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the questions you posted the last few days, you've got a corrupt server.

The `.TMD` is a temporary file, so move that to your `/tmp` directory,

```
mv wp_posts.TMD /tmp
```

and then try to do a [repair table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/repair-table.html) from the official MySQL 5.5 documentation.

If that fails, your last hope will be [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/corrupted-myisam-tables.html).

Comment: `/tmp` is enough ;)